# Pymongo3.6 check_keys not doing it's job

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I need dots in my keys in mongo. So, while inserting I am sending 'check_keys = False'. This was working fine for pymongo3.4. But I recently updated to pymongo3.6 and I am getting the InvalidDocument Error even when I am sending check_keys=False. Is there any way around this problem?

```
db['test'].insert([{'a.b': 'asd'}], check_keys=False}
```

Please try this out using both Pymongo3.6 and Pymongo3.4

Answer (score 0):

Use [`insert_one`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) method instead as `insert` is deprecated, and supply `bypass_document_validation=True` parameter.

Comment: What's your MongoDB version?

Comment: db['test_col'].insert_one({'asd.s':'asdqd'}, bypass_document_validation=True)

packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 649, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise error
InvalidDocument: key 'asd.s' must not contain '.'

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue, and I found that `update_one` seems to not care about the dot (`.`), so I'm considering to create an empty object first, with `insert_one`, then add the contents to it later using `update_one`, that way bypassing that limitation. Not the cleanest solution, but could do the trick.